# Regex 301 redirects

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, woocommerce, redirect

Using `Wordpress/Woocommerce` latest versions:

I need to 301 redirect my old shop urls to my new site that has cleaner urls, but with over 2000 urls, I am looking automate this, as much as possible. Hopefully a regex pattern in the .htaccess can do this? I have very limited knowledge of how to do this, so any help would be much appreciated.

OLD URL FORMAT

```
foobar.com/vintage-industrial/3135-sgabello-alto-cindy-industrial-arredamento-industrial-sgabello-.html
foobar.com/shabby-e-provenzale/3270-cubo-cottage-2-cassetti-arredamento-shabby-chic-etnico-nordico.html
foobar.com/mobili-etnici/3286-armadio-lambert-blue-arredamento-etnico-classico.html
foobar.com/mobili-etnici/3335-tavolo-telgede-80-tavolo-rustico-industrial-arredamento-etnico-arredamento-industrial.html
foobar.com/sedie-sgabelli/1687-sedia-jenny-arancio-sedie-colorate-pop-vintage.html
```

the above example shows a directory, which can be anything, followed by the product id and name

NEW URL FORMAT

```
foobar.com/prodotto/sgabello-alto-cindy
foobar.com/prodotto/cubo-cottage-2
foobar.com/prodotto/armadio-lambert-blue
foobar.com/prodotto/tavolo-telgede-80-tavolo
foobar.com/prodotto/sedia-jenny-arancio
```

every new url will be in this simple format & all will have the 'prodotto' base url

The old url's have a lot of keywords stuffed into them, which have been removed from the new url's

**UPDATE**

Is there a way I can strip out this part of the old url's:

```
'vintage-industrial/3135-'
```

I think this is all I may need to do, as mod_rewrite should find the product from the remaining part of the url? So i would be left with

```
foobar.com/sgabello-alto-cindy-industrial-arredamento-industrial-sgabello
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide few more examples to make it clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically we have:

`foobar.com/type/####-product-name-and-key-words.html`

that will be translated into

`foobar.com/prodotto/product-name`

If you only have a few of the types we can do something like this:

```
RewriteRule "^/first-type/[0-9]+-(.*)\.html$" "/prodotto/$1"
RewriteRule "^/second-type/[0-9]+-(.*)\.html$" "/prodotto/$1"\
```

Which is safer, but somewhat tedious if you have a lot. We could also do this:

```
RewriteRule "^/.*/[0-9]+-(.*)\.html$" "/prodotto/$1"
```

Which is faster, but has a slight risk of matching things we don't want. Either way we will be left with `foobar.com/prodotto/product-name-and-key-words`

> I think this is all I may need to do, as mod_rewrite should find the product from the remaining part of the url?

If it does then that's great! We're done. If not, we'll have to continue.

If you don't have an easy to follow rule for separating name from keywords, then we'll have to get a little more creative. We can [override WP's 404 page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page) with our own code. This 404 page will do something very strange. It will strip the last section of its url off (based on dashes/slashes) and redirect to the cut down url. This way we will progressively approach the right page:

```
foobar.com/type/####-product-name-and-key-words.html
foobar.com/prodotto/product-name-and-key-words
foobar.com/prodotto/product-name-and-key
foobar.com/prodotto/product-name-and
foobar.com/prodotto/product-name
```

This has the negative affects of having a lot of redirects, but being permanent their browser should learn. It also means you effectively can't have a 404 page, as it will progressively strip the url down till you reach your home page.

Comment: Thanks for the response Kallmanation, I am going to try your first solution, as I think we only have a small number of categories (less than 10 I think), so this could work!

Comment: Your first approach has given me a good idea on how to achieve this, so I'll report back when I have an update!